# Spring AMQP - Proper way to register queues to container on startup

Tags: java, spring, amqp, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have a situation where I need to register queues dynamically in a run-time to a `SimpleMessageListenerContainer`. The problem I am experiencing is a deadlock that happens because of this:

```
Thread: [52] Thread1 wants the lock java.lang.Object@5537e0df
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.getDeferredCloseExecutor(CachingConnectionFactory.java:907)
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.restart(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:739)


Thread: [183] Thread2 wants the lock java.lang.Object@556fa9d6
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.queuesChanged(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:689)
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:634)
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createBareChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:578)
```

[image]

and this is the code that is problematic - here I try to setup client queues in `onCreate` callback in `connectionListener`.

```
connectionFactory
        .addConnectionListener(
            new ConnectionListener() {
              @Override
              public void onCreate(Connection connection) {
                setupClientQueues(); ----> will call container.setQueueNames which will result in calling queuesChanged
              }

              @Override
              public void onClose(Connection connection) {
                // nothing to do
              }
            });
```

Is there some standard (proper) way to easily register and create queues dynamically without causing this deadlock?

**UPDATE**

This is how I handle it now, after Garry suggestion:

```
  @Bean
  public SmartLifecycle containerQueueSetter(){
    return new SmartLifecycle(){
      private boolean running;

      @Override
      public int getPhase() {
        return 0;
      }

      @Override
      public void start() {
        //CREATE QUEUES HERE - since I create and register them as beans,
        //it will work even when rabbit is reconnected
        //REGISTER QUEUES TO SIMPLE_MESSAGE_LISTENER_CONTAINER
        running = true;
      }

      @Override
      public void stop() {
        log.info("Stopping dynamic queue registerer.");
        running = false;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean isRunning() {
        return running;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean isAutoStartup() {
        return true;
      }

      @Override
      public void stop(Runnable callback) {
        stop();
        callback.run();
      }
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to implement `SmartLifecycle` and do the setup in `start()`.

The listener container default `phase` is `Integer.MAX_VALUE` so the containers are amongst the last things started by the application context.

Put your `SmartLifecycle` in an earlier phase (e.g. 0) so the containers will be set up before starting.

Comment: Will this work if connection is broken and then other rabbit is connected to (failover) that has no queues created etc. ?

Comment: If you need to create the queues on the broker as well as add them to the container(s), you should do the queue creation in a connection listener but add them to the container in the SmartLifecycle.

Comment: There should be no problem if I set queue names to `ListenerContainer` before connection is established (not sure if this is possible at all but...)? I thing that spring will just retry re-connecting to rabbit server if it cannot connect on start (but other threads will run all Bean inits etc.).

Comment: btw. this problem is experienced only on rabbit failover. On normal restart it works OK.

Comment: I currently have dynamic queues registered as beans in a runtime `if (!context.getBeanFactory().containsBean(queue.getName())) {
      context.getBeanFactory().registerSingleton(queue.getName(), queue);
    }` so this should actually handle queue recreation on failover. Does SimpleMessageListenerContainer preserves queue bindings between failovers? Since if it does then I do not need to re-register at all.

Comment: It's much more efficient to add the queues while the container is stopped. If you are registering the queues with the application context, they will automatically be re-declared after failing over. Yes, the container will try to consume from the same queues after a failover.

Comment: OK. Let me just confirm one more time. I can register queues dynamically in runtime as beans (like my code above), and then Spring will handle queue re-creation on rabbit failover. Also, I need only once to do `container.setQueueNames` and then on failover (since names of queues are not actually changed), `SimpleMessageLC` will continue consuming messages from queues that are re-created on the new rabbitMQ. This means that I can listen for `ContextStartedEvent` and then register all queues as beans dynamically and call `contnr.setQueueNames` only at that time. Spring will take care from there.

Comment: All correct except `ContextStartedEvent` is too late - the containers are already started when that is emitted. Again; the best technique is a `SmartLifecycle` in an earlier phase than the container(s).

Comment: will try that. tnx.

Comment: Seems working now. I only needed to remove queue creation from connection listener, since SMLC would try to listen to queues before they were created on rabbit and then fail (since it cannot find queues). Now I register queues in SmartLC (as beans), so they are created before SMLC is run.

Comment: Just one more comment here, since I just got problem with bindings - seems like they also have to be registered as beans otherwise binding will not be recreated on rabbit failover...

Comment: Just checking my code - on actual startup if I put 0 as a phase, I still need container injected as a dependency. In this case, seems like spring is not waiting for Integer.MAX phase to start container bean, but starts it before it is injected as a dependency into my SmartLifeCycle bean. This way, I cannot add queues before bean is started. I guess I would need to declare bean as autoStart(false), and start it only inside my SmartLifeCycle bean (after I add queues)?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. The registry is started in the last phase (`Integer.MAX_VALUE`); as long as your bean is in an earlier phase it is guaranteed to be started before the registry. Perhaps it's time to ask a new question with your current configuration if you are still having difficulty. The admins here don't like long commentary.

Comment: I created new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58713801/problem-adding-queues-using-smartlifecycle-at-runtime . Can you please check also this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58661518/simplemessagelistener-vs-directmessagelistener

Comment: Now I see what you are saying; see my answer over there.

Comment: Now I see what you are saying; see my answer over there. Regarding the other question, I didn't answer it because someone pointed out that it's a possible duplicate of another that I answered.

Comment: The other question that seems like duplicate has partial answer. My question is a bit more complex than that.